# What are these PCB calibration standards?

Tags: shunt, instrumentation

I found these shunt resistors in a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpowsour.2022.231407) that uses them to calibrate AC equipment for EIS testing. They used the "frequency dependent complex impedance response" of these standards to calculate the error coefficients.

I'm interested in implementing the same method myself but am having trouble finding these. I tried looking up PCB calibration standard, PCB shunt resistor but couldn't find anything with known inductive properties.

Not sure if these are custom PCBs or if they are commercially available and would really appreciate it if someone could point me to where I can find/make some of these.

[image]

Comment: They probably made them themselves. Have you tried emailing the paper author to see if they can shed any details?

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to figure out the impedance as a function of frequency if I were to make one myself? And yes I did email them, haven't heard back yet and thought I'd try my luck here too.

Comment: Ideally you would need an impedance analyser to measure frequency dependent impedance (its possible to do with a VNA too). If you don't have a dedicated one, you could potentially cobble something together using a sig-gen and oscilloscope, but that may just be trading one calibration issue with another.
It suggests in the paper that they compared them with a tracable calibrated impedance standard from their lab.

Answer (score 0):

The term "standard" is not the thing that you first thought of, such as IEC-... or EN-... . Yes, sounds confusing.

A **standard** is basically a reference for error-corrected measurements and measurement devices. All of its useful properties *(complex impedance, delay, thermal-related, loss factor, etc.)* are known and don't change from measurement to measurement. So it can be used as a reference.

A standard can be a SHORT (Zero Ohms), OPEN (Infinite Ohms), LOAD, etc. But in practice we know that nothing can be exactly zero Ohms, or infinite Ohms (because we don't know what number is) or 10.0000000000000000000000000000000000....00 milliohms.

So, the standards are created to have parameters which are "constant" and "close enough to desired value", just to define the zero, max, and error of a measurement and/or a device i.e. to say, for example, "0.003 milliohms is my zero". Hence the name **standard**.